# how webserver handle multiple requests?

Tags: multithreading, webserver

I've read many posts on the internet including stackoverflow about how webserver works. Answers differ from each other in the posts. I really wonder what is the most correct answer on that topic.

- User IP: UI
- User Port: UP
- Server IP: SI
- SERVER PORT: SP
- PROTOCOL: P

**Scenario:**

- I want to visit [www.example.com/file.php](http://www.example.com/file.php) (IP: SI and PORT: SP)
- TCP Connection established between user and server
- In the server site, Apache listening on the SP port all the time.
- The http request from browser /GET file.php
- Apache finds file.php and want php to proccess it and send it back to
  apache
- Apache retrieves output from php and send it back to user
- User browser renders it at application level.

This is what I know, what I don't understand here, how does Apache behave when multiple connection made. Does Apache creates new thread for every connection? If so, how do those threads communicate to the users?

I hope my question was clear. Thank for anyone helping me understand this concept.